# column line are not sync in datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have added one datagrid control to show employee details and binded with ObservableCollection.
I have grouped the data based on country.
but now problem is that, column header's vertical line (line which separate out the columns) not sync with the column data.(the lines in the data part of the grid, is moved slightly right with respect to the header lines.)

if I remove group header then column header vertical line sync with columns data.
Is there any property to sync the line with entire column?

below is the xaml code

```
 <Grid>
        <Custom:DataGrid x:Name="dgData" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                         CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Custom:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle >
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <DockPanel Background="LightBlue">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100"/>

                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </Custom:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
                <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact" Binding="{Binding Contact}"/>
                <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Email ID" Binding="{Binding EmailID}"/>
                <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
            </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
        </Custom:DataGrid>
    </Grid>

below is code behind file

     public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ObservableCollection<Employee> empData = new ObservableCollection<Employee> 
            {
                new Employee{Name="Diptimaya Patra", Contact="0000", 
                    EmailID="diptimaya.patra@some.com", Country="India"},
                new Employee{Name="Dhananjay Kumar", Contact="00020", 
                    EmailID="dhananjay.kumar@some.com", Country="India"},
                new Employee{Name="David Paul", Contact="1230", 
                    EmailID="david.paul@some.com", Country="India"},
                new Employee{Name="Christina Joy", Contact="1980", 
                    EmailID="christina.joy@some.com", Country="UK"},
                new Employee{Name="Hiro Nakamura", Contact="0000", 
                    EmailID="hiro.nakamura@some.com", Country="Japan"},
                new Employee{Name="Angela Patrelli", Contact="0000", 
                    EmailID="angela.patrelli@some.com", Country="Japan"},
                new Employee{Name="Zoran White", Contact="0000", 
                    EmailID="diptimaya.patra@some.com", Country="Scotland"},
            };

            ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(empData);
            collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Country"));
            dgData.ItemsSource = collection;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to set [GroupStyle.ContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.containerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property too.

I have modified your code with following.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                 CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <DockPanel Background="LightBlue">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact" Binding="{Binding Contact}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email ID" Binding="{Binding EmailID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or

you can use like this too.

```
 <StackPanel Background="LightBlue" Orientation="Vertical">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
     <ItemsPresenter />
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: but it shows expander. I don't want to show expander in grid.

Comment: but it shows expander. I don't want to show expander in grid.

Comment: I tried below one but it doesn't solve my problem.               <StackPanel Background="LightBlue" Orientation="Vertical">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
     <ItemsPresenter />
 </StackPanel>